# How to calculate the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-a}(\log n)^b$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-zeta

Assume, $a>1,b>0$, how to calculate the infinite sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-a}(\log n)^b$$

I tried with WolframAlpha, I found that this sum converge bu running `sum (1/n^a)*(log n)^b, n=1 to infinity`, But it does not give a result. How to calculate this sum?
It seems does not has a closed form. But how can I write the result with the $\zeta$ function?

Comment: Why should there exist a closed form ? (even for $b=0$, this is $\zeta$ function and it has no closed form...)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks for your reply. It does not matter if it is not a closed form. But how can I write it with a $\zeta$ function? It has an extra term than the simple $\zeta$ function.

Comment: It's $(-1)^b\zeta^{(b)}(a)$, provided you [suitably define](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) arbitrary derivatives. (The power of $-1$ [also requires caution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponentiation).)

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for your answer. Do you know where I can find the answer to do this sum step-by-step?

Comment: It's a notation for the $b$th derivative with respect to $a$. To compute it, notice $n^{-a}=e^{ka}$ with $k=-\ln n$.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for your hint. I'm sorry for not being quite familiar with the calcus. Is it possible to give more details about this?

Comment: Maple agrees with the  @J.G. answer provided I tell it to assume $b$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @StevenClark Thanks! May I know how to calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\log^b(n)\ n^{-s}\right)=(-1)^b\ \zeta^{(b)}(s)\tag{1}$$

where

$$\Re(s)>1\land b\in\mathbb{Z}\land b>0\tag{2}$$

so the formula

$$\zeta^{(b)}(s)=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left((-1)^b\ \sum_{n=1}^N \log^b(n)\ n^{-s}\right)\tag{3}$$

can be used to evaluate the $b^{th}$-order derivative of $\zeta(s)$ for $\Re(s)>1$.

---

The formulas above are based on the term-wise differentiation

$$\frac{\partial\, n^{-s}}{\partial s}=-\log(n)\ n^{-s}\tag{4}$$

which leads to the more general result

$$\frac{\partial^b\, n^{-s}}{\partial s^b}=(-1)^b\, \log^b(n)\ n^{-s}\tag{5}.$$